# How should I send content to output window using Juce framework in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, juce

I'm having trouble outputting any messages to my output window in Visual Studio 2012.

```
std::cout << "string"
```

The above does not work in that there is no content sent to the debug window.

But I also found a DBG function that JUCE uses, i.e.

```
DBG("message")
```

But that produces the same result, no message sent to the output window.

I continued to research and eventually found that I should be using the OutputDebugString function for debugging in visual studio, which I used in the following code (look at the initialise function halfway down),

```
#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
#include "Logn.h"
#include "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\stdafx.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//==============================================================================

class MainWindow : public DocumentWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow() : DocumentWindow ("JUCE Hello World!", Colours::lightgrey, DocumentWindow::allButtons,true)
    {
    setContentOwned(new Window(), true);
    centreWithSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    setVisible(true);
}

~MainWindow()
{

}

void closeButtonPressed() override
{
    JUCEApplication::quit();
}
};

class Test_1Application : public JUCEApplication
{
public:
//==============================================================================
Test_1Application() {}

const String getApplicationName() override       { return ProjectInfo::projectName; }
const String getApplicationVersion() override    { return ProjectInfo::versionString; }
bool moreThanOneInstanceAllowed() override       { return true; }

//==============================================================================
void initialise (const String& commandLine) override
{
    // Add your application's initialisation code here..
    mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    OutputDebugString("My output string.");
}

void shutdown() override
{
    // Add your application's shutdown code here..
    mainWindow = nullptr;
}

//==============================================================================
void systemRequestedQuit() override
{
    // This is called when the app is being asked to quit: you can ignore this
    // request and let the app carry on running, or call quit() to allow the app to close.
    quit();
}

void anotherInstanceStarted (const String& commandLine) override
{
    // When another instance of the app is launched while this one is running,
    // this method is invoked, and the commandLine parameter tells you what
    // the other instance's command-line arguments were.
}
private:
    ScopedPointer<MainWindow> mainWindow;
};

//==============================================================================
// This macro generates the main() routine that launches the app.
START_JUCE_APPLICATION (Test_1Application)
```

However, the above also doesn't work, and produces the following error message,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NewProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\user\programming\cpp\source\main.cpp(53): warning C4100: 'commandLine' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>c:\users\user\programming\cpp\source\main.cpp(78): warning C4100: 'commandLine' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>c:\users\user\programming\cpp\source\main.cpp(90): error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded
1>          c:\users\user\programming\cpp\source\main.cpp(90) : see declaration of 'WinMain'
1>c:\users\user\programming\cpp\source\main.cpp(90): error C2733: 'WinMain' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winbase.h(2188) : see declaration of 'WinMain'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I started a new project without using JUCE, and the OutputDebugString function works perfectly.

So the problem is the JUCE framework doesn't play well with the OutputDebugString function, which seems to be the only function I can use to output anything to the debug window in Visual Studio.

Please help me figure out how this should all be working and what I need to do to fix it. I'm fairly new to C++, visual studio, and JUCE, so this is a bug hurdle for me to fix. And all I'm trying to do is output hello world to the output window. >:(

Comment: Can't really help you with your problem, but there is an alternative that you might want try. You can initialize a console/terminal window with `AllocConsole()` and then print to it with normal cout/printf and even _cprintf. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't getting an output from DBG because the program isn't compiling.  Try removing all the #includes apart from the juce one.  It won't compile with outputDebugString either, unless you change it to...

```
    Logger::outputDebugString("blah");
```

... but you should use the DBG macro anyway (because the statements are only compiled in debug builds).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue here with

```
DBG("message");
```

but it turned out that i was clicking the "start without debugging button", instead of the "Local Windows Debugger Button".

[image]

when i use the Local Windows Debugger Button all my messages showed up in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for ages but I have just discovered a tab at the bottom of the output window in Visual Studio 2022 that is called "Immediate Window". Messages from JUCE DBG("message") do appear there.